# How to read NSArray from coredata entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to read a coredata entity into a NSMutableArray however I keep getting back weird lots of data. For instance when I get back an NSDictionary of values it looks like this

```
data: {
    companyName = "WPremium";
    desc = "Test";
    guid = "Otq12342";
    install =     (
        "0x1e59e910 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p851>",
        "0x1e59e8e0 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p848>",
        "0x1e59e830 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p837>",
        "0x1e59e930 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p853>",
        "0x1e59e850 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p839>",
        "0x1e59e890 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p843>",
        "0x1e59e8b0 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p845>",
        "0x1e59e7c0 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p830>",
        "0x1e5957e0 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p829>",
        "0x1e59e810 <x-coredata://BAF7B1AD-F357-455A-B9D7-1288F7D1F652/Install/p835>",
        "(...and 16 more...)"
    );
```

I would like to know how to put the install object of the coredata dictionary into an NSArray so I can sort it.

Update: this is how I call my coredata object.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)readSelectedInstall:(NSString *)projIDString {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    
    
    if (context == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
    }
    else {
        
        
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"InstallProject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"projID==%@",projIDString];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        
        NSError *error;
        
        NSMutableArray *installProjectDictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        for (InstallProject *installProj in fetchedObjects) {
            
            NSMutableDictionary *tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.companyName forKey:@"CompanyName"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.projNo forKey:@"ProjNo"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.desc forKey:@"Desc"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.guid forKey:@"GUID"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.projID forKey:@"ProjID"];
            [tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray setObject:installProj.install forKey:@"install"];
            
            [installProjectDictionaryArray addObject:tempInstallProjectDictionaryArray];
        }
        
        return installProjectDictionaryArray;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

then with the returning NSMutableArray I do this

```
NSMutableArray *getarray = [self readSelectedInstall:projIDString];
    
    NSMutableDictionary *installsDictionary = [getarray objectAtIndex:0];
    
    NSMutableArray *tempInstalls = [installsDictionary objectForKey:@"install"];
    NSLog(@"%@", tempInstalls);
    
    NSArray *tempSortedItemsArray = [tempInstalls sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                                     @[[NSSortDescriptor
                                        sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dp" ascending:YES],
                                     [NSSortDescriptor
                                      sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dc

" ascending:YES]]];
    
    tempInstalls = [tempSortedItemsArray mutableCopy];
    tempSortedItemsArray = nil;
    
    

    
    NSLog(@"%@", tempInstalls);
```

but on that last line of code is where I have the weird output.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is fetch the core data NSManagedObject from Core Data, install would be returned as an NSSet, by the looks of things it is an NSSet of NSManagedObjects.

Once you have the object you access the "install" property and sort however you want.

```
// Get the Core Data Object (Uses Magical Record)
MyObject *object = [MyObject MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate objectPredicate:self.users_id]];
// Sort the object set into an array
NSArray *installs = [object.install sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:k_timestamp ascending:YES] ]];
```

Comment: I have updated my question, with how I get the object.. I thought this might help you asnwer the question.

Comment: I just read on another questin you should use NSSet.. Im looking that up now.

Comment: @HurkNburkS I think what you are doing is right. Don't rely entirely on NSLog, what are you hoping to do with the object?

Comment: I am trying to update a entity in my coredata base that is a child to another entity. I actually have no idea how to do it, I was thinking of reading it updating the entity item then write it back to coredata but that seems so redundant.. so now im looking for another way to do this.

Comment: For (item in parentItem.children) { item.attribute=xxx; }; [moc save];